# VBA Excel: Error during range selection during workbooks iteration

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have several files in one folder with the column "Part Number" but not all of them are in the same column number. The list doesn't necessarily start in the same row either.

So I first look for the string "Part Number", then copy its address as the start of the range I want to copy.

The column "Part Number"has some blank spaces in some items, so I couldnt use .End(xlDown) to search the last row.

So I use the column "Qty" to find the last row and copy the row number.

I have the cell where the range starts, the column number and the row number where the range should finish. However I get an error "Application defined or object defined error".

The macro is not finished but I cannot move forward until I solve this. This is what I got:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mergeworkbooks()


Dim path As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcolumn As Long
Dim rangestart As String
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim rangefinish As String
Dim activesht As String


path = "D:\RubenBK\TEST\"
filename = Dir(path)

       Do While filename <> ""

              Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & filename)
              For Each wks In Worksheets
                    If Not wks.UsedRange.Find("PART NUMBER", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
                    wks.UsedRange.Find("PART NUMBER", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Activate
                    rangestart = wks.UsedRange.Find("PART NUMBER", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Address
                    lastcolumn = wks.UsedRange.Find("PART NUMBER", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
                    lastrow = wks.UsedRange.Find("qty", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).End(xlDown).row
                    rangefinish = Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn).Address(xlA1)
                    activesht = ActiveSheet.Name

                    'AND HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR, THE Range("rangestart: rangefinish") PART:

                    wbk.Sheets(activesht).Range("rangestart: rangefinish").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10")
                    End If
                    wbk.Close
              Next
        filename = Dir
        Loop


End Sub
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are `rangestart` and `rangefinish` defined as when you get to the error? The `.address` is most likely stopping it from working. Also, the `range("var1: var2")` might have an error

Comment: They are defined like $D$6 and $D&10. gtwebb suggestion worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is you have your **rangestart** and **rangefinish** wrapped in the quotes.

Try moving them outside the quotes and it should work.

```
wbk.Sheets(activesht).Range(rangestart & ":" & rangefinish).Copy
```